# Direct selection is edting all cornes of a rectangle

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am reading a tutorial. The author drags a rounded corner away from the rectangle to remove it. I do the same and all corners are altered. I am using CC 2015 the sames as the author.

Comment: What is your question? It sounds like you're trying to turn a rounded corner into a sharp corner using the live corner feature in Illustrator.

Answer (score 1):

With the Direct Selection Tool <kbd>A</kbd>, click on the shape to select it.

Click on the corner widget once, to select it

Then do a second click and drag on the selected corner widget to move it

Example

[image]